# aws glue IAM role cant connect to aws opensearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-glue

I have a Glue job to push data into AWS OpenSearch. Everythings works perfectly when I have an "open" permission on OpenSearch, for example:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:<region>:<accountId>:domain/<domain>/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

This works without issue. The problem is I want to secure my OpenSearch domain to only the role running the glue job.

I attempted to do that starting basic with:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::<accountId>:role/AWSGluePowerUser"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This disables all access to OpenSearch which I want, however it also blocks it for Glue even though the jobs a running with the `AWSGluePowerUser` role set.

```
An error occurred while calling o805.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'
```

Which I assume is because the Glue job can no longer see the OpenSearch cluster. Keep in mind everything works when using the "default" access policy for OpenSearch.

I have my glue job configured to use the IAM role `AWSGluePowerUser` which also has `AmazonOpenSearchServiceFullAccess` policy attached.

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong here?

Edit: Here is where/how I've set the roles for the Glue job, I assume this is all I needed to do?

From Glue Job Details
[image]

Comment: Try your original policy but only with the principal changed to the `AWSGluePowerUser` ARN instead of changing it all - what do you get?

Comment: And have you deleted or recreated the AWSGluePowerUser since applying the policy?

Comment: @Ermiya Eskandary to your first point, yes I've tried that however the results are still the same. How do I prove that the glue job is calling to OpenSearch using the `AWSGluePowerUser` role and not something else? I suspect this is where my actual issue lies.

Comment: You can verify it by giving that role a deny all policy and seeing if stuff continues to work. I don't think it will, but that's how you would try it :)

Comment: Could you provide more details about how you set up your Glue job to connect to Opensearch to begin with? I have a cluster with open permissions I'm trying to connect to, but am struggling to find good references as to how to connect in general.

Comment: Perhaps open a question and I can attempt to answer it

Comment: Thanks. Posted, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73366759/connecting-to-aws-opensearch-with-glue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is not possible because the AWS Glue Elasticsearch connector is based on an open-source Elasticsearch Spark library that doest not sign requests using AWS Signature Version 4 which is required for enforcing domain access policies.

If you take a look at the [key concepts for fine-grained access control in OpenSearch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html#fgac-concepts), you'll see:

> If you choose IAM for your master user, all requests to the cluster must be signed using AWS Signature Version 4.

If you visit the [Elasticsearch Connector for AWS Glue AWS Marketplace page](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-v5ygernwn2gb6), you'll notice that the connector itself is based on an open-source implementation:

> For more details about this open-source Elasticsearch spark connector, please refer to this [open-source connector online reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html)

Under the hood, AWS Glue is using this library to index data from Spark dataframes to the Elasticsearch endpoint. Since this open-source library (maintained by the Elasticsearch community) does not have support for signing requests using using AWS Signature Version 4, it will only work with the "open permission" you've referenced. This is hinted at in the [big picture on fine-grained access control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html#fgac-access-policies):

> In general, if you enable fine-grained access control, we recommend using a domain access policy that doesn't require signed requests.

Note that you can always fall back us using a master user based on username/password:

1. Create a master user (username/password) for the OpenSearch domain's fine-grained access control configuration.
2. Store the username/password in an AWS Secrets Manager secret as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/tutorial-step1.html).
3. Attach the secret to the AWS Glue connector as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/tutorial-step3.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is correct, and the conclusion I've also come to. Shame it isn't more obvious/clearly documented on AWS side. Have fallen back to using the fine-grained controller. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

I usually take a "deny everyone except" approach in these situations

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "es:*",
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ArnNotLike": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": [
                        "arn:aws:iam::<accountId>:role/AWSGluePowerUser"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is interesting and I wasn't aware you could write policies like this, however it still fails with the same problem. I suspect the role `AWSGluePowerUser` isn't being used to call to OpenSearch but I don't know how I can confirm that?

Comment: I re-read the error you're getting and your question edit.  I think `AWSGluePowerUser` doesn't have the correct perms/policies attached.  Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64870093/3437504) will help